# Truncating cells in csv file

Tags: python-3.x

im currently trying to create a piece of software that finds and truncate cells containing more than a set number of characters in .csv files.

here's where i'm at :
    import csv

```
with open('test.csv', 'r', newline = '', encoding = "UTF-8") as csv_file, \
     open('output.csv', 'x',newline='',encoding="UTF-8") as output_file:

        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csv_file.read(2048))
        dialect.escapechar = '\\'
        csv_file.seek(0)
        writer = csv.writer(output_file, dialect)
        for row in csv.reader(csv_file, dialect) :
                copy = row
                for col in copy :
                        #truncate the file to desired lenght
                        col = col[:253] + (col[:253] and '..')
                writer.writerow(copy)
```

The problem here is that the new file is created but not changed.

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, is that you recreate the value col. This means that the old value is not changed and it is the old value that is still in the list. Best is to recreate the original list, and this can be done best with a "list comprehension"

```
copy = [col[:253] + (col[:253] and '..') for col in copy]
```

What's more, it really does not do anything if your variables have the same name. So, you named your altered value col, the same name as your loop variable, but this not mean that that what's contained by that loop variable (so the value in the list copy) is now replaced.

That's also why you don't have to do copy = row. You can just use row.

Comment: I think `copy = [col[:253] + (col[:253] and '..') for col in row]` is what you meant furthermore now that I can see the edit it seems that `col[:253] + (col[:253] and '..')` adds dots on each cell not just on the truncated ones

Comment: Kind of, copy is really not needed at all. Also, the colon is just wrong placed. So it is `row = [col[:253] + (col[253:] and '..') for col in row]`

Comment: It works, thanks, i'll need to work on understanding how python's variables work.

Comment: So, the technical bit: All variables in Python are objects, but the actual value of the variable are just the value of the reference to the object, which can be extracted with `id()`. This value can be used to extract the contents of the object, or used to adjust the contents of that object. The latter however is only possible if the that object was a mutable object in the first place, like a list. However, a string is an immutable object, just like integers. https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747